# User auth without service in meteor js

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

Can I create a new user without using any third-party service? I am developing an application where I need to treat equally anonymous users that registered.
Then if the anonymous user to register can update their data while maintaining the same uuid.
Is it possible? 
I'm using the branch auth-dropdown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the auth-dropdown branch, but I'm using the "auth" branch.

The Meteor team recently introduced a new API to register/login users without using the Google/Facebook login system.

They have a guide on how to get started with the auth branch on their Wiki: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Getting-Started-with-Auth

You can see that they've introduced Client-Side APIs like:

```
Meteor.loginWithPassword(user, password, callback)
Meteor.createUser(options, extra, callback)
Meteor.changePassword(oldPassword, newPassword, callback)
Meteor.logout()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's just what I needed. Thanks a lot!